# Not able to get initial data for django form

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

here is the django form Which is django user change form

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'mobile' , 'gender')
        widgets = {
        'gender': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = User.objects.get(email=self.request.user.email)
            first_name = user.first_name
            last_name = user.last_name
            mobile = user.mobile
            gender = user.gender

        self.fields['first_name'].initial = first_name
        self.fields['last_name'].initial = last_name
        self.fields['mobile'].initial = mobile
        self.fields['gender'].initial = gender
```

this is the error i am getting

```
'UserChangeForm' object has no attribute 'request'
```

here is the view

```
class UserProfileEditView(DetailView):
    template_name = "edit_profile.html"

    def get(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        context = {}
        edit_form = UserChangeForm()

        context['edit_form'] =  edit_form

        return render(request , self.template_name , context)
```

here is the traceback

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\accounts\views.py" in get
  54.         edit_form = UserChangeForm()
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\accounts\forms.py" in __init__
  58.         if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
```

how can i get initial data for the fields in django form?
Thank you

**edited** after **MHassan's** response

here is the form

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        intial_data = self.kwargs.get('initial')
        request = intial_data.get('request')

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
            first_name = user.first_name
            last_name = user.last_name
            mobile = user.mobile
            gender = user.gender

        self.fields['first_name'].initial = first_name
        self.fields['last_name'].initial = last_name
        self.fields['mobile'].initial = mobile
        self.fields['gender'].initial = gender
        del self.fields['gender'].widget.choices[0]
```

here is the view

```
def get(self , request , *args , **kwargs):
        context = {}
        edit_form = UserChangeForm(initial={'request': request})

        context['edit_form'] =  edit_form

        return render(request , self.template_name , context)
```

here is the traceback

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\accounts\views.py" in get
  54.         edit_form = UserChangeForm(initial={'request': request})
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\accounts\forms.py" in __init__
  58.         intial_data = self.kwargs.get('initial')
```

Comment: show code for your view.

Comment: view added to the question@MHassan

Comment: I have posted answer. You will use `get_initial` function for sending initial data to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django request object isn't available by default in the Form class so you have to pass it by yourself:

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        # Call super() after deleting the extra kwargs.
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Other code
```

And pass it when you create the form in your view:

```
def update(request):
    form = UserChangeForm(request=request)
```

Comment: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Comment: If you're getting that error, then you haven't copied Gianluca's code correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot@Gianluca